# SQL query Optimization -- Use Subqueries or not

Tags: sql

So I have two queries

```
select key, A, B, C, D, E, F
from
(select key, A, B, C from table1) t1
join 
(select key, D, E, F from table2) t2
on t1.key = t2.key
```

and

```
select key, A, B, C, D, E, F
from
table1 join table2 
on table1.key = table2.key
```

Are these queries the same in terms of querying time?
If not, which one runs faster and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, a good optimizer *might* execute the first subquery version using the second's query plan.  But if not, then the first query might execute more slowly than the second.  This is because the subqueries on the two tables would force your SQL database to materialize the two tables as intermediate result sets, before joining them.  Doing so takes execution time, space, and also precludes the use of any index during the join of the subqueries.  So, you should probably lean towards using the second version.